# move IP address from one interface to another without interruption

Tags: linux, ip

When I need to move IP address from one interface to another, I have usually done simply for example `ip addr flush dev eth0; ip addr add 10.10.10.181/26 dev eth0.35` over an SSH session. So far I have never been disconnected, but is there a theoretical possibility, that `ip addr flush dev eth0` is executed before `ip addr add 10.10.10.181/26 dev eth0.35` command reaches remote machine? Does this somehow depend on SSH configuration?

Comment: Run the commands as an `at(1)` job, not interactively.  Then you don't care if you get disconnected.  You should still make sure you have some other way in though, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: If you extend a little more the post to describe why you are doing that, we might be able to suggest you an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the full command is already on the remote machine.

There is no guarantee that this will not cause a disconnect but the reason it hasn't impacted your session so far is that the system didn't have time to notice the disconnection which actually happened.  Processes which are receiving data while it gets disconnected will probably notice it.

There is no work-around to make it shorter or faster than what you're doing right now, and a service disruption of less than a second is not something that should be worrisome unless you do it too often.

Comment: I overlooked that the characters are transmitted to remote machine immediately when I type those. Not when I push the `Enter`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Proper way of doing this is to put those commands in a simple shell script and executing this script, after transferring it to the remote machine, by a single remote ssh command rather than two commands on one line, separated by a semicolon. Normally, as Julie said, it is not something to worry about but it is not bullet-proof either.

Also, consider, some network switches do no like MAC address changes for the same IP address too frequently. And this gets worse if your interfaces operate in some sort of a aggregate configuration (fail-over type or fat-pipe type aggregation I am talking about here)

Comment: MAC addresses do not change between virtual interfaces in the same NIC, that is why the OP is getting away with it.

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked the interface name of `eth0.35`. My bad...

Comment: I wouldn't consider this any more "proper". A shell prompt is just an interactive shell script. Executing the commands from a file, or from STDIN (using `;` instead of newlines) is the same thing.